# Make batch command wait until it builds Visual Studio solution/deploy an Android app on simulator

Tags: visual-studio, batch-file

using batch script I am deploying a Xamarin Android app on simulator. The command is working fine but its not waiting for the results of the deploy action, instead it is executing the next command with out waiting for the result of the deploy action. I need to take action based on deploy success or failure. I tried this code:

```
::Build the solution
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.com" /run release "C:\Users\xxxxx.sln"

:WAITLOOP
if "%ERRORLEVEL%"=="0" goto RUNNING
goto NOTRUNNING

:RUNNING
goto WAITLOOP

:NOTRUNNING
::Next statements
```

But this code is running in infinite loop. Any suggestions on who to make batch script wait until the build result before it proceeds to next statement.

Comment: `start "" /WAIT "...\devenv.com" ...`?

Comment: And run in a command prompt window `if /?` to get displayed help of command __IF__ which explains already at top the `if errorlevel Number Command` syntax explained more detailed in Microsoft support article [Testing for a Specific Error Level in Batch Files](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/69576). Here it would be enough to use `if errorlevel 1 goto NOTRUNNING`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use /build not /run to not open the IDE per https://learn.microsoft.com/sv-se/visualstudio/ide/reference/devenv-command-line-switches

```
::Build the solution
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.com" /build "C:\Users\xxxxx.sln"
if "%ERRORLEVEL%"=="0" goto ok
echo Did not compile correctly
goto end

:ok
::Next statements

:end
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Bernhard but Visual studio wont create apk file up on just build, we need to run the project in order to create apk file. and run command is opening the IDE with solution and running the app, But its not waiting until it completes the deployment.